# why is register (or numeric representation of register) not present in machine instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I'm currently studying the x86 assembly language by following Kip Irvine's book "Assembly language for x86 processor 7th Edi".

In chapter 4, the author talked about machine instruction

[image]

My question is, why is `al` (or a representation of `al`) not present in the machine instruction `A0 00010400`? If `al` is absent, how can the machine know we want to move the value at address `00010400` to `al`?

============ **Edit 1** ===============

I tried `mov bl var1` and a machine code was generated for `bl`

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.STACK 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.DATA
var1 BYTE 10h

.CODE 
    main PROC 
    MOV BL, var1 

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

[image]

Comment: It's implied by the opcode -- see e.g. http://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html and e.g. chapter 17.2.2 in https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2006/readings/i386/s17_02.htm describes how to read it.

Comment: The target register is *implicit* in the opcode.  While it might seem wasteful to dedicate an opcode to just one register, this mattered a great deal 43 years ago.  Memory was very expensive back then, making code as compact as possible was a strong goal.  It still helps today, memory is still expensive.  Not in dollars but in execution speed.

Comment: There's a reason `[r/e]a[x/h/l]` has an `a` in its name. It's the **accumulator**. Similarly, the other "general purpose" registers in x86 have specific uses where they have shorter encodings (or are the only possible / implicit operand).

Comment: hi AkiSuihkonen & Hans, thank you both for the comment. Correct me if I'm wrong, my current understanding is that when we use `mov` with  `al, ah, ax, eax, rax`, then there will be no machine instruction generated for `al, ah, ax, eax, rax`,  becuase they are the default for `mov`. To prove myself, I have tried `mov bl var1` and a machine instruction was generated for `bl`. So is my understanding somewhat correct?

Comment: More correct way is to say, that the instruction doesn't contain an explicit field for the register. There are OTOH encoding of the same instruction where also al,ax, etc. is explicitly present -- usually assembler will select the shortest encoding, and few assemblers AFAIK allow selecting of alternative encoding. According to the same linked table, AH does not have a dedicated opcode, but has to be encoded explicitly.

Comment: While it's only aesthetics issue in MASM, I strongly suggest to use the correct Intel syntax: `mov al,[var1]` with the square brackets, to keep this in sync with memory dereferencing through register (`mov al,[esi]`, not `mov al,esi` and `mov eax,esi` is just copy between registers). Using square brackets with every memory dereference makes it easier to spot every memory access while reading the source later, the `mov al,var1` looks like ordinary reg->reg value copy on first sight. Also the `mov al,[var1]` is more compatible with other assemblers (TASM in ideal mode, and NASM)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule the register value **is** present in the machine instruction.
However there is a lot of legacy 'baggage' in the x86 instruction set.
When the 8086 was introduced the length of the instruction had an effect on the execution time: shorter instructions ran faster.

The `A` register (`AX/AL`) is called the 'accumulator' and used to be the most versatile register in the CPU. It has special short versions of instructions that (used to) run faster (on the original 8086/8088). In later iterations of the x86 the other registers were upgraded to be more general purpose. Nowadays you can pretty much use any register for all purposes.

You can see this clearly on the x86 opcode map, see: http://sparksandflames.com/files/x86InstructionChart.html

Note that `mov al,[absolute address]` has 2 encodings which do the same thing:
A0 and 8A 05

```
0:  a0 00 00 00 00          mov    al,BYTE PTR ds:0x0
5:  8a 05 00 00 00 00       mov    al,BYTE PTR ds:0x0
```

In retrospect, this is wasteful. But it seemed like a good idea at the time to make instructions using the accumulator register faster. Due to backwards compatibility these mistakes cannot be corrected now.
There was a chance to eliminate this duplication in the new X64 instruction set, but AMD did not want to make too many changes, so we are permanently stuck with these historical artefacts.

Comment: In 64-bit mode, the `A0` and `A1` opcodes are the only way to load from a 64-bit absolute address without having it in a register.  e.g. `mov eax, [0x123456789ABCD]`.  IDK if that's ever useful in trampoline or shim functions that can't easily save/restore registers.

Comment: I agree it's too bad that commercial reasons (and wanting to share decoder silicon) led to missing an opportunity to clean up x86 machine code, though.  AMD might have done more if they were sure that AMD64 would catch on, and that it wouldn't just be rarely-used stuff they'd have to support.  If Intel+AMD had got together and agreed on something that would be better for x86 in the long term, that would have been great.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is, why is `al` (or a representation of `al`) not present in the machine instruction `A0 00010400`?

Because there is a special encoding of the `MOV` instruction (`0xA0`) that *always* has the `AL` register as its destination operand. The rest of the code bytes are dedicated to specifying the source operand, which in this case is `0x00010400`—the address of `var1` in the `.DATA` section.

You can see that in [this table](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_1.htm). You'll also see that there are other special encodings for instructions, like `0xA1` for a `MOV` with `AX`/`EAX` as its destination operand, and `0xA2` for a version of `MOV` with its operands reversed (*e.g.*, `mov var1, al`).

The *reason* why these alternative encodings exist is to save bytes in the resulting machine code. As [Hans Passant commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233757/why-is-register-or-numeric-representation-of-register-not-present-in-machine-i#comment77433447_45233757), that kind of thing mattered a lot in the mid- to late-1970s when the x86 processor was conceived and designed. Memory was *very* expensive back then, and bus speeds much slower, so conserving space was important—even at the expense of making the processor's instruction decoder more complicated. Given the very small (4-byte) fetch queue on the 8088, using these special one-byte encodings of instructions can [significantly increase the speed of a particular sequence of code](https://trixter.oldskool.org/2013/01/10/optimizing-for-the-8088-and-8086-cpu-part-1/). Now, however, with this design still being used some 40 years later, this is some of the legacy baggage of the x86 platform that Intel continues to suffer with. Modern x86 chips have to dedicate a disproportionately large portion of their silicon to a complex instruction decoder, even though memory is so cheap now that these types of optimizations don't really help anyone.

These special encodings aren't *just* available for when one of the operands is the accumulator register, but [that is by far the most common case for a special encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019386/what-is-the-significance-of-operations-on-the-register-eax-having-their-own-opco/38019602#38019602).

Normally, though, instructions *are* encoded with an opcode byte, followed by bytes for each operand. This is what you are seeing with `mov bl, var1`. The opcode for `mov reg8, r/m8` is `0x8A`. This is followed by `0x1D` to specify the `DL` register as the destination operand. There is [a handy opcode table here](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/reference/Instructions_by_Opcode.html), or you can find this information in Intel's IA-32 architecture manuals for each individual instruction. [This site](http://ref.x86asm.net) is very useful, providing "cheat sheets" for instructions. You'll find lots more links like this in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Some/older(/CISC) instruction sets, particularly ones that use 8 bit or variable length starting with 8 bit instructions like the x86.  Instead of what you see in mips or arm or other (risc in particular) instruction sets where it is usually crystal clear that these N bits call out a specific register.  For these 8 bit based instruction sets (say x86, 6502, z80, etc) you create a list of instructions you want to implement and then line them up often in a way that makes sense for decoding, and at times some of the bits might actually indicate a register.  Look at a opcode chart for 8086 or z80 or other and see the patterns.  At the same time it is somewhat arbitrary, I have say 157 instructions I can use a single byte to  represent up to 256 things, done.  just list the things and assign a number to them.  The logic has a table inside basically that turns it in to microcode (for microcoded architectures like x86 and 6502, etc, but not risc in general that wouldnt make any sense), likewise decoding or reading the machine code you have to refer to the table thus the reason why a lot of "whatever instruction set reference" documents often start with an opcode map, even ARM but in the ARM case it deals with the fraction of the word that determines what family then the rest of the bits clearly indicate register numbers, etc.  in CISC like z80, 8086, etc the opcode map is often the bytes, the 256 possible instructions and each byte might uniquely define the whole operation, inputs, outputs, then any immediates follow that as part of the variable length.