# How to interpret x86-64 instruction bytes based on the assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code

I created a simple assembly program. A few Qs:

1. each instruction below starts with 0x48. However, I dont see that as a part of the instruction from this references:
   http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x89

E.g., x05 is the add instruction that adds immediate to a register, but not 0x0548. Similar for other instructions below.

2. How are rax, rbx encoded in the binary? E.g. Why using rbx is a byte more than rax?

   ```
     401000:   48 05 34 12 00 00       add    rax,0x1234
     40100c:   48 81 c3 34 12 00 00    add    rbx,0x1234
   ```
3. Same questions as bove, but a diff example. Why changing the source register to rbx, causes a change from c0 to d8?

   ```
    401006:    48 01 c0                add    rax,rax
    401009:    48 01 d8                add    rax,rbx
   ```

```
  $ objdump -d assembly_test
  
  assembly_test:     file format elf64-x86-64
  
  
  Disassembly of section .text:
  
  0000000000401000 <_start>:
    401000:   48 05 34 12 00 00       add    rax,0x1234
    401006:   48 01 c0                add    rax,rax
    401009:   48 01 d8                add    rax,rbx
    40100c:   48 81 c3 34 12 00 00    add    rbx,0x1234
    401013:   48 c7 c0 34 12 00 00    mov    rax,0x1234
    40101a:   48 89 c0                mov    rax,rax
    40101d:   48 89 d8                mov    rax,rbx
```

Comment: Your executable is ELF, not [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (which is Windows's executable format), but anyway that isn't relevant to the instructions in it.  Also, when asking questions about assembly, please always include the tag for the architecture.  I've removed the [tag:portable-executable] tag and added [tag:x86-64].

Comment: It is the [REX prefix](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix), that's why you see rax instead of eax.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding.  Re: `add rax, imm32` special-case opcode without a ModRM byte: [What is the significance of operations on the register EAX having their own opcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019602). 
 See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160739) for some other EAX special cases.

Comment: re: question 1, the REX.W prefix: you similarly don't see a `66` operand-size prefix in the manual entry for `add r16, r/m16` (like `add ax, bx`), but you need one in 32 and 64 bit modes where the default operand-size is 32.

Comment: Please refer to the Intel Software Development Manuals for how the encoding works.

Comment: If reading SDM solves the problem, I wont ask here. Reading SDM vol2A. 2.2.1.2 More on REX Prefix Fields
REX prefixes are a set of 16 opcodes that span one row of the opcode map and occupy entries 40H to 4FH. These
opcodes represent valid instructions (INC or DEC) in IA-32 operating modes and in compatibility mode. This however, did not tell me about the register values